# I've installed "dash" but still see "bash" when I login via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, bash, arm

I've configured my Raspberry Pi to use "dash" for default shell, as [instructed here](http://blog.extremeshok.com/debian/raspberry-pi-raspbian-tuning-optimising-optimizing-for-reduced-memory-usage/).

I have Dropbear for SSH.

When I login via SSH, I still see the "bash" console, and not "dash".

How to change this and forget bash?

Comment: It's a useful question but strictly speaking is off-topic.

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but please [search](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following command line :

```
chsh -s $(type -p dash)
```

Comment: I'd run `type -p dash` first, just to be certain the system can find it. You don't want to risk setting your default shell to an error message. (Ok, it wouldn't actually do that, but still.)

Answer (score 0):

type `dash` that should do it, but really you should use `chsh` and change shell permanently